# getting error while install jsPDF 2.5.1 on nuxtJS

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, jspdf

I am using **jsPDF** v.1.5.3 and it **ok** but when I installed **V2.5.1** I get this **error** .

[image]

[image]

[image]

so, How can I **Fix** this ?

**stackes** : nuxtjs + typescript+ property decorators + vuetify

Comment: You could probably start from here: https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/releases Checking what are the differences between the previous and latest version, looking for any breaking changes. You're doing a big leap here, so it's kinda legit that it breaks. Also, be sure to isolate the rest of your stack to have less issues debugging overall.

Comment: `these dependencies were not found`, check that you've installed everything properly and also that you've only touched to `jsPDF`.

Comment: @kissu all dependencies are installed , actually this error happens when I add this npm package , without it it works fine

Comment: @kissu 
the breaking change is adding typescript types

Comment: Which NPM package?

Comment: I guess that you have some strict errors if you do not type all of the codebase.